# How to assign an IP for Hyper-V virtual machine using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, ip, hyper-v, vagrant

I'm working with the Hyper-v and have created a VM using Vagrant.
Seems to be in the `Vagrantfile` I've forgotten to define an IP address (static or dhcp use).

Now I can view the info about the VM's network adapter.

```
get-vm -n 2012R2 | Select -ExpandProperty NetWorkAdapters
```

And the result info is the next:

```
Network Adapter False 2012R2 VM Virtual Switch 00155DFA9F01 {Degraded, ProtocolVersion} {}
```

As you can see the MAC address is defined, the switch is the external one.
But the last property value (which relates to the bound IP-address) is NOT defined.

Does exist the way to set manually the IP address for the VM machine in Hyper-V using Powershell or even GUI manager (didn't find possibility to set an IP in GUI).

Answer (score 2):

You can use PowerShell Direct to connect to the VM directly from the Hyper-V Host. [PowerShell Direct](https://web.archive.org/web/20160204202435/https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2015/05/14/powershell-direct-running-powershell-inside-a-virtual-machine-from-the-hyper-v-host/) uses the VM bus to talk to the inside of the VM (as long as it runs a current windows). It bypasses the network stack and is made for exactly this. Needs really newish OS though (it says preview, but look at the date - predates Server 2016).

Then you can just change the IP address....

https://www.howtogeek.com/112660/how-to-change-your-ip-address-using-powershell/

Command(s) look like this:

```
New-NetIPAddress –InterfaceAlias “Wired Ethernet Connection” –IPv4Address “192.168.0.1” –PrefixLength 24 -DefaultGateway 192.168.0.254
```

Or you use DHCP ;) But that is not what you ask ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to assign IP address to the specific MAC address.

```
netsh DHCP server <DHCPserverIP> scope <scopeIP> add reservedip <reservedIP> <MAC Address>
```

Regards,
Pemil